# Possible to use double DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns

Before I used my plesk DNS and found that there is no SPF records in plesk and now I left plesk and started using Godaddy DNS and here I found that there is no PTR records in Godaddy DNS. But I need both PTR and SPF records. Now can I use both Plesk and Godaddy DNS together or  is there any issue in using more than one DNS service for a same domain?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is configure your SPF record with GoDaddy and have your ISP configure your reverse DNS record. This should accomplish what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. You need to have one authorative DNS server and can setup others to be slaves that replicate the zone(s). But this is not an easy task and can't be done via a (web)frontend.

Comment: PTR and SPF records are in different zones and thus can very well live on a different set of DNS servers.